# NodeJS re-installation on Windows 10 fails

Tags: node.js, reinstall

I had installed nodejs on Windows 10 Pro PC. The drive it was installed in failed and is no longer accessible. I sent it away for data recovery attempt, but it's now gone, not even connected.

I created a restore point and went to NodeJS site, downloaded the installer anew, and tried to re-install it.

The installer looks for that original installation and immediately responds: "Invalid Drive: O:" (the old location). It then immediately quits.

What can I do to re-install it? I can't uninstall it or do anything else (change, or repair). They all give the same message and quit.

Can I uninstall it from the command prompt? Or do a new installation that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by editing the following registry value

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Node.js
```

There you will find an InstallPath property. Rename the drive to a valid one and then try to install node again.

Also remove Node from your PATH variable

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why that hadn't occurred to me. I take it you meant remove the old invalid setting for the PATH variable. Thanks again.